# jquery link problem?

Tags: jquery, hash, hyperlink, tags

when a user clicks a link on the site, instead of loading a whole other page jquery just loads the content into the content div in the middle of the page, but when a user direct links to a page it does not do this is there a way to make this happen when a user direct links to a page

www.scotwebtech.co.uk and navigate to aboutus ( how i want it to look)

http://www.scotwebtech.co.uk/aboutus.html (how it looks when a user direct links)

Comment: if you are using php you can handle it in .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

actually the user should directly link to http://www.scotwebtech.co.uk/#aboutus.html and not http://www.scotwebtech.co.uk/aboutus.html

change the links pointing to http://www.scotwebtech.co.uk/aboutus.html to include the # character.

Comment: when i do change all the links to #linkname.html the jquery that changes the content stops working

Comment: I tested it...do you have it up?

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions:

1 . Design the "about us" page in the same way as your other pages, then use [jQuery's load() method](http://api.jquery.com/load) to extract the content you are looking for

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

Not the best way though, since you are still loading a lot of html that you do not need, but it should work.

2 . Depending on your will to use a script language on your server you could let a script decide if to deliver the complete page (on normal requests) or just the content (on AJAX requests)